UnauthorizedAccessException with ProvisioningAgent.GetProvisionedProfile in UWP App
I'm encountering an issue while developing a UWP application. When calling the ProvisioningAgent.GetProvisionedProfile method, I'm getting an UnauthorizedAccessException. Here's the relevant code snippet:
Error Message
2024-09-29 16:38:13.0030 INFO +++MainPage+++ UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
2024-09-29 16:38:13.0030 INFO +++MainPage+++ HResult: -2147024891
2024-09-29 16:38:13.0061 INFO +++MainPage+++ StackTrace:    at Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.ProvisioningAgent.GetProvisionedProfile(ProfileMediaType mediaType, String profileName)
   at UWP_ESim02.MainPage.CellularSwitch()

 public void CellularSwitch()
 {

     var mobileBroadbandAccounts = MobileBroadbandAccount.AvailableNetworkAccountIds;
     if (mobileBroadbandAccounts == null || mobileBroadbandAccounts.Count == 0)
     {

         return;
     }



     var mobileBroadbandAccount = MobileBroadbandAccount.CreateFromNetworkAccountId(mobileBroadbandAccounts[0]);
     if (mobileBroadbandAccount == null)
     {

         return;
     }

     Logger.Log($"NetworkAccountId: {mobileBroadbandAccount.NetworkAccountId}");

     try
     {
         //var provisioningAgent = ProvisioningAgent.CreateFromNetworkAccountId(mobileBroadbandAccount.NetworkAccountId);


         ProvisionedProfile cellularProfile = new ProvisioningAgent().GetProvisionedProfile(ProfileMediaType.Wwan, "cellular");

         cellularProfile?.UpdateCost(NetworkCostType.Unrestricted);
     }
     catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
     {
         Logger.Log($"UnauthorizedAccessException: {ex.Message}");
         Logger.Log($"HResult: {ex.HResult}");
         Logger.Log($"StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Logger.Log($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
         Logger.Log($"HResult: {ex.HResult}");
         Logger.Log($"StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
     }

 }

Capabilities
    <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
        <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer"/>
        <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>
        <rescap:Capability Name="networkConnectionManagerProvisioning"/>
        <rescap:Capability Name="networkDataPlanProvisioning"/>
        <rescap:Capability Name="deviceManagementDmAccount"/>
        <rescap:Capability Name="packagePolicySystem"/>
        <rescap:Capability Name="networkDataUsageManagement"/>
        <rescap:Capability Name="appCaptureSettings"/>
        <rescap:Capability Name="cellularDeviceIdentity"/>
        <rescap:Capability Name="cellularDeviceControl"/>
        <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication"/>
        <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/>
        <uap4:CustomCapability Name="Microsoft.eSIMManagement_8wekyb3d8bbwe"/>
        <uap4:CustomCapability Name="Microsoft.cellularSARConfiguration_8wekyb3d8bbwe"/>
        <DeviceCapability Name="cellularData"/>
        <DeviceCapability Name="wifiControl"/>
        <DeviceCapability Name="mobileDeviceInfo" />
        <DeviceCapability Name="mobileDeviceInformation" />
        <DeviceCapability Name="networkDataPlanProvisioning" />
        <DeviceCapability Name="registryRead"/>
        <DeviceCapability Name="registryWrite"/>
        <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
    </Capabilities>


Declared cellularData and other relevant capabilities in Package.appxmanifest.
Ensured the device is in developer mode.
Tested on a real device.

